# Error:variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.?

Tags: django

i've deployed  login related  project in server its not working properly and error showing variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.in console 
In URL GETTING Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Url:http://djangoprojectstr.pythonanywhere.com/

ERROR:: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environ
ment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: It's hard to help when we can't see the code you tried.

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/FollowingTheDjangoTutorial/? If so did you make sure you set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable properly in your `wsgi.py` to match your project name and/or the path to your settings module?

Comment: yes .i has done

Comment: i deployed other project in the same way it has done but this only i am problem for login related projects any extra settings i required?